# How can I automate this, open location list and set its position for man filetype?

Tags: neovim

```
export MANPAGER="nvim +set\ filetype=man -"
```

I have this under my shell configuration, I've been using neovim as my man pager and one thing I love most is its table of contents functionality, pressing `gO` or by calling `man#show_toc()` function. Currently when I open a man page with `man fzf` command for example, pressing `gO` would bring location list at the bottom of the window like this

[image]

and the thing I want to see is this,

[image]

but it should be open automatically every time when I run man command.

```
call man#show_toc() | quit
vertical topleft lopen
vertical resize 40
setlocal nonumber norelativenumber
wincmd p
```

I could do by entering these commands by hand or putting them in a file named `ftplugin/man.vim` but still it doesn't feel right, such like syntax highlighting doesn't work. Is there any better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to install an autocmd listening to `FileType qf`, which would check whether the title of the location window is `Man TOC`, and which would reposition the latter on the far left of the screen (+ resize it):

```
augroup reposition_man_toc
    au!
    au FileType qf  call s:reposition_man_toc()
augroup END

fu! s:reposition_man_toc() abort
    let title = get(getloclist(0, {'title':1}), 'title', '')
    if title isnot# 'Man TOC'
        return
    endif
    wincmd H
    vert resize 40
endfu
```

---

If you want the location window to be automatically opened, [as you suggested](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15330/how-can-i-automate-this-open-location-list-and-set-its-position-for-man-filetyp#comment26261_15332), you could also try to add a 2nd autocmd:

```
au FileType man call man#show_toc()
```

Which would give:

```
augroup reposition_man_toc
    au!
    au FileType man  call man#show_toc()
    au FileType qf  call s:reposition_man_toc()
augroup END

fu! s:reposition_man_toc() abort
    let title = get(getloclist(0, {'title':1}), 'title', '')
    if title isnot# 'Man TOC'
        return
    endif
    wincmd H
    vert resize 40
endfu
```

Or maybe you could install a single autocmd:

```
augroup open_toc
    au!
    au FileType  man  call s:open_toc()
augroup END

fu! s:open_toc() abort
    call man#show_toc()
    let title = get(getloclist(0, {'title':1}), 'title', '')
    if title isnot# 'Man TOC'
        return
    endif
    wincmd H
    vert resize 40
endfu
```

---

As rightly pointed out by [Christian Brabandt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15330/how-can-i-automate-this-open-location-list-and-set-its-position-for-man-filetyp#comment26268_15332), you could simplify the code by using the window-local variable `w:quickfix_title`, and eliminate the call to `getloclist()`. It would give:

```
augroup open_toc
    au!
    au FileType  man  call s:open_toc()
augroup END

fu! s:open_toc() abort
    call man#show_toc()
    if w:quickfix_title isnot# 'Man TOC'
        return
    endif
    wincmd H
    vert resize 40
endfu
```

Comment: Thanks, it works quite good but I said it should be automatic process, can you add `au FileType man call man#show_toc()` too, so I can accept this answer.

Comment: Thank you so much spending your time for your answer! I'm grateful.

Comment: Since you are using `au FileType qf  call s:reposition_man_toc()` you could simply check the window title variable `w:quickfix_title` instead of the `getloclist()` call

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Honestly I don't even check with `getloclist()`, because it turns out to be useless, we are calling function `man#show_toc()`, it will open `Man TOC` list without a doubt. I use this version now. https://gist.github.com/kutsan/f1a4edb737e6121d85be7407901b7d58